# Calling a function multiple times but it prints only once

Tags: c++, function, output

I'm running the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string response(bool isMale, bool isTall)
{
    if (isMale && isTall) {
        cout << "MALE AND TALL" << endl;
    }
    else if (isMale || isTall) {
        cout << "MALE OR NOT TALL" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "ELSE" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    response(true, true);
    response(false, true);
    response(false, false);

    return 0;
}
```

the output is the following:

```
MALE AND TALL

Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)   execution time : 1.460 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Why isn't the output?:

```
MALE AND TALL

MALE OR NOT TALL

ELSE
```

A different forum post hinted at a global value not being reset. I don't really know what to make of that.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You promised to return a `string` from `response()`, but you didn't `return` anything. Your program can do anything, including crash (like it does now), doing nothing, doing what you wanted or formatting your C:/ drive.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior world, man!

Comment: It would benefit you greatly to [enable warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/K44PnEeTc) in your build environment.

Comment: you told your compiler to compile a function that returns a `string` without returning a `string`, no matter what the compiler does, it will be equally right or wrong

Answer (score 6):

```
void response(bool isMale, bool isTall){
    if (isMale && isTall) {
        cout << "MALE AND TALL" << endl;
    }
    else if (isMale || isTall ){
        cout << "MALE OR NOT TALL" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "ELSE" << endl;
    }
}
```

You need to change function return type "string" to "void".